# javascript clearInterval issue

Tags: javascript, setinterval, horizontal-scrolling, clearinterval

so i wanna make a page to  scroll horizontally left&right when mouse moves 100px near to the edges of the browser window. i wrote the following script but it refuses to clear interval when the mouse moves to the middle of that page.

edit: sorry for not pasting the whole js here, startScrollLeft and ..Right already defined as a global var. i made a dummy page [here](http://alic.in/hScroll). you can check the page and how my code is (not) working.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){

        var cursorX = e.pageX;

        if (cursorX > windowW - 100){
            startScrollLeft = setInterval(scrollLeft, 50);
        }else {
            clearInterval(startScrollLeft);
        }

        if (cursorX < 100){
            startScrollRight = setInterval(scrollRight, 50);
        }else{
            clearInterval(startScrollRight);
        }

    });
    var scrolledAmount = 20;
    function scrollLeft(){
        if($('.content').width() > scrolledAmount + contentW +  windowW - 400){
            $('.content').animate({
                left: '-='+20+'px'
            },70, 'linear');
            scrolledAmount = scrolledAmount+20;
        }
    }
    function scrollRight(){
        if(scrolledAmount > 20){
            $('.content').animate({
                left: '+='+20+'px'
            },70,'linear');
            scrolledAmount = scrolledAmount-20;
        }
    }
```

need a hand with this issue :/

Comment: Where are contentW and windowW being set and what are they being set to?

Comment: this is just a wild guess and hence a comment, but it looks like if the user holds his mouse over the right side of the screen, it will keep making interval timers.  Your variable is a local one, meaning there is a new copy made every time mousemove is triggered.  Try making the variables global and always clear it before assigning startScrollRight/startScrollLeft.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use set startScrollLeft and startScrollRight as global vars

```
var cursorX = e.pageX;

if (cursorX > windowW - 100){
    window.startScrollLeft = setInterval(scrollLeft, 50);
}else {
    clearInterval(window.startScrollLeft);  
}

if (cursorX < 100){
    window.startScrollRight = setInterval(scrollRight, 50);
}else{
    clearInterval(window.startScrollRight);
}
```

Comment: startScrollLeft and startScrollRight are already global since they're assigned without var.

Comment: If you do this:  clearInterval(startScrollLeft) it will generate an error because startScrollLeft was never defined (if the mouse starts in the middle, that is something fairly common)

Comment: Did you mean this for me? You're right and that could be part of the problem, but that's unrelated to the scoping issues in this thread. You might want to suggest in your answer or in a comment above that the OP define the variables first.